# Consume Web Service Through VPN Server

Tags: web-services, wcf, remote-access, vpn, remote-server

So, I have to consume a web service in my application. But the service host limited the access to the certain remote server (where the final application will reside).

As I am currently developing it I want to consume the web service from my local machine.

Is there any possible way to do this? Or should I contact the service provider to allow access from my local machine too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the WSDL and the XSDs of the service, you can generate a service reference from those files.

If you want to make the actual calls, you'll also need to [generate a service interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335699.aspx) (search the web for something like "WFC Schema First svcutil"), and implement the service yourself, using stubs.